# How to convert this JSON object into a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert this json code to a python dataframe. I've been using a json converter to convert this to csv. It appears that the columns values are before the colon. Should I just wrap a list of the column names? My end goal is to optimize the importing data process flow.
This is a sample json data. I keep reading answers of people converting this. No need for the full column. Just need help on getting started.

```
data = {
  "address": [
    {
      "state": "22"
    }
  ],
  "birthDate": "1952-11-17",
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables/race",
      "valueCoding": {
        "code": "1",
        "display": "White",
        "system": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables/race"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables/rfrnc_yr",
      "valueDate": "2021"
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "id": "-10000000000066",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables/bene_id",
      "value": "-10000000000066"
    },
    {
      "system": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/identifier/mbi-hash",
      "value": "0e239e4895a76a2aff678507b1626a7cd08d23db07280e7efa228c8b0c156d23"
    },
    {
      "extension": [
        {
          "url": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/codesystem/identifier-currency",
          "valueCoding": {
            "code": "current",
            "display": "Current",
            "system": "https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/codesystem/identifier-currency"
          }
        }
      ],
      "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi",
      "value": "1S00E00AA66"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00"
  },
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Schneider199",
      "given": [
        "Werner409"
      ],
      "use": "usual"
    }
  ],
  "resourceType": "Patient"
}
```

Comment: Please create a few rows and columns of data in google spreadsheet or excel file, with the data you have, and show how your table columns would look like. No coding here. First you need to have clarity on which fields from the json go into the table and where. And please add a screenshot of it, to help people see what you want. 
You JSON file has multiple levels and hence, either you need to pick various fields from those levels, or, you need to use multi-index. But it all starts with you specifying how your table would look like first.

Answer (score 1):

For getting started:

You may convert your JSON into format like this

```
data = {
    'columnname1': [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...],
    'columnname2': [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...],
    ...
}
```

or, if you want multiple index levels,

```
data = {
    ('level1', 'level2', 'columnname1): [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...],
    ('level1', 'level2', 'columnname2): [entry1, entry2, entry3, ...],
    ...
}
```

Also, make sure all lists contain the same number of entries.

In either formats, you can convert it into a DataFrame with

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

in the way that your keys become column names, and the list of entries for that key become values of the corresponding column.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your sample dict to `pd.Dataframe`, you have to ensure the lengths of all arrays are identical.

Your sample data incorporates different data types with various lengths, i.e. list with length of 3, string, integer. In this case, you can not convert it to dataframe because (1) string, integer those data types are not array except list; (2) they are not in the same size

Here is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# Turn all values in dict to arrays
for x,y in data.items():
    data[x] = [y]

# Convert dict to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

However, the output I believe is not the final output you desire, perhaps you could provide us a sample output like Excel table, screenshot, etc., to draw a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is the following. I define a function that alows me to flatten any json file:

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

Then simply do the following:

```
results = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

outdf = flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which returns:

```
 index   birthDate gender               id resourceType  \
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
..    ...         ...    ...              ...          ...   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   
0       0  1952-11-17   male  -10000000000066      Patient   

                 meta.lastUpdated address.state  \
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
..                            ...           ...   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   
0   2021-08-17T13:43:00.037-04:00            22   

                                        extension.url  \
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
..                                                ...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...   

   extension.valueCoding.code extension.valueCoding.display  \
0                           1                         White   
0                           1                         White   
0                           1                         White   
0                           1                         White   
0                           1                         White   
..                        ...                           ...   
0                         NaN                           NaN   
0                         NaN                           NaN   
0                         NaN                           NaN   
0                         NaN                           NaN   
0                         NaN                           NaN   

                         extension.valueCoding.system extension.valueDate  \
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...                 NaN   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...                 NaN   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...                 NaN   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...                 NaN   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...                 NaN   
..                                                ...                 ...   
0                                                 NaN                2021   
0                                                 NaN                2021   
0                                                 NaN                2021   
0                                                 NaN                2021   
0                                                 NaN                2021   

                                    identifier.system identifier.value  \
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...  -10000000000066   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...  -10000000000066   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...  -10000000000066   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...  -10000000000066   
0   https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources/variables...  -10000000000066   
..                                                ...              ...   
0                      http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi      1S00E00AA66   
0                      http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi      1S00E00AA66   
0                      http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi      1S00E00AA66   
0                      http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi      1S00E00AA66   
0                      http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-mbi      1S00E00AA66   

                                 identifier.extension   name.family name.use  \
0                                                 NaN  Schneider199    usual   
0                                                 NaN  Schneider199    usual   
0                                                 NaN  Schneider199    usual   
0                                                 NaN  Schneider199    usual   
0                                                 NaN  Schneider199    usual   
..                                                ...           ...      ...   
0   [{'url': 'https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources...  Schneider199    usual   
0   [{'url': 'https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources...  Schneider199    usual   
0   [{'url': 'https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources...  Schneider199    usual   
0   [{'url': 'https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources...  Schneider199    usual   
0   [{'url': 'https://bluebutton.cms.gov/resources...  Schneider199    usual   

   name.given  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
..        ...  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  
0   Werner409  

[20736 rows x 18 columns]
```